# How to optimise a schedule?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm looking for a little help with structuring an algorithm for ressource allocation.
Here are the parameters :

- I have a list of ressources, and time slots for those ressources. I format this as an array [Ressource, time, person]. This represent all my available slots.
- I have a list of people, and their requested ressource under the format [person, ressource_needed_1, ressource_needed_2, etc].
- Persons do not mind at what time they get to use the ressource.

My current approach is to loop through the people, giving them the first ressource available, and moving on to the next person. I repeat this loop until no request can be fullfilled for anyone.

This is what is looks like graphically :

| Ressource | Time | Person |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 08:00-09:00 | John |
| A | 09:00-10:00 | Mary |
| A | 10:00-11:00 | David |
| B | 08:00-09:00 | David |
| B | 09:00-10:00 | Claire |
| B | 10:00-11:00 | John |
| C | 08:00-09:00 |  |
| C | 09:00-10:00 | John |
| C | 10:00-11:00 | Claire |

Now let's say, David is next for allocation, and has requested to use ressource C, but it is only avalable at 8, and he is already using ressource B at that time. With my current loop, he can't get ressource C. However, we have multiple ways to solve this (for exemple, in this case we could simply switch claire to 8 am, but there are more complicated situations where finding the solutions require changing almost the entire schedule).

How can I structure an algorithm to solve this ?

Comment: The area of study for this is called "Organizational Research" or **OR**. The general problem that you are trying to solve is called the bin packing problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). The bad news is that this is known to b NP-complete. That means you are trying to solve a problem that is known in computer science for being among the hardest problems in computing (not necessarily hard to program but hard to compute, given enough people a naive algorithm may take days or even months to find a solution)...

Comment: ... Fortunately OR is an active area of research because companies need to solve such problems to make money. There are quite a few popular OR libraries such as Google's OR Tools (https://developers.google.com/optimization). Most of the algorithms developed to solve this don't attempt to get perfect optimization but instead to get a good enough solution.

Comment: I think you meant operations research.

Comment: This question is better suited to https://or.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @pjs That's interesting, since the two phrases have completely different meanings in English. There is "organizational behavior" and "organizational pyschology," which are of course very different subjects. What country uses "organizational research?"

Comment: @Gene It’s Operations Research in the US, I’ve heard it referred to as Operational Research in the UK and Australia. I haven’t heard anybody refer to it as Organizational Research.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion to find out all possible allocations of resources, and select the best out of it.

Example Program: (Python)

```py
import copy
def show(l,r,t):
    print("Possible resource allocations:")
    for n,result in enumerate(l):
        print("\nAllocation #%d:"%(n+1))
        for i in range(len(result)):
            for j in range(len(result[i])):
                print("%s - %s : %s"%(r[i],t[j],result[i][j]))

def get_res(rq,i):
    for n,res in enumerate(rq):
        if n==i:
            return res

def get_possible_persons(rm,rq,i,j):
    persons=[]
    persons.extend(rq[get_res(rq,i)])
    if len(persons)==0:
        #Case1: there is no request for the empty slot
        return (1,persons)
    for row in rm:
        if row[j] in persons:
            persons.remove(row[j])
    #Case2: if empty, there is no valid person from request
    return (2,persons)

def get_next_open(resource_map,n,m):
    for i in range(len(resource_map)):
        for j in range(len(resource_map[i])):
            if resource_map[i][j]==None:
                if i>n or (i==n and j>m):
                    return (i,j)
    return (None,None)

result={}
def add(rm,l):
    if l in result:
        result[l].append(rm)
    else:
        result[l]=[rm]

def allocate(resource_map,requests,i=-1,j=-1,level=0):
    (i,j)=get_next_open(resource_map,i,j)
    if i==None or j==None:
        add(copy.deepcopy(resource_map),level)
        return
    case,persons=get_possible_persons(resource_map,requests,i,j)
    if len(persons)==0:
        add(copy.deepcopy(resource_map),level)
        if case==1:
            allocate(resource_map,requests,i,j,level+1)
        else:
            return
    for person in persons:
        resource_map[i][j]=person
        requests[get_res(requests,i)].remove(person)
        allocate(resource_map,requests,i,j,level+1)
        requests[get_res(requests,i)].append(person)
        resource_map[i][j]=None
def get_dict_from_list(lst):
    dict={}
    for l in lst:
        name=l[0]
        for res in l[1:]:
            if res in dict:
                dict[res].append(name)
            else:
                dict[res]=[name]
    return dict
def main(request_list, time_slots):
    requests=get_dict_from_list(request_list)
    number_of_resources=len(requests)
    number_of_slots=len(time_slots)

    resource_map=[]
    for _ in range(number_of_resources):
        resource_map.append([None]*number_of_slots)
    allocate(resource_map,requests)
    
    s=sorted(result)
    show(result[s[-1]],list(requests.keys()),time_slots)

request_list=[["john","A","B","C"],["mary","A"],["david","A","B","C"],["clair","B","C"]]
time_slots=["8-9","9-10","10-11"]
main(request_list,time_slots)
```

Output:

```
Possible resource allocations:

Allocation #1:
A - 8-9 : john
A - 9-10 : mary
A - 10-11 : david
B - 8-9 : david
B - 9-10 : john
B - 10-11 : clair
C - 8-9 : clair
C - 9-10 : david
C - 10-11 : john

Allocation #2:
A - 8-9 : john
A - 9-10 : mary
A - 10-11 : david
B - 8-9 : clair
B - 9-10 : david
B - 10-11 : john
C - 8-9 : david
C - 9-10 : john
C - 10-11 : clair

Allocation #3:
A - 8-9 : john
A - 9-10 : david
A - 10-11 : mary
B - 8-9 : david
B - 9-10 : clair
B - 10-11 : john
C - 8-9 : clair
C - 9-10 : john
C - 10-11 : david

Allocation #4:
A - 8-9 : john
A - 9-10 : david
A - 10-11 : mary
B - 8-9 : clair
B - 9-10 : john
B - 10-11 : david
C - 8-9 : david
C - 9-10 : clair
C - 10-11 : john

Allocation #5:
A - 8-9 : mary
A - 9-10 : david
A - 10-11 : john
B - 8-9 : david
B - 9-10 : john
B - 10-11 : clair
C - 8-9 : john
C - 9-10 : clair
C - 10-11 : david

Allocation #6:
A - 8-9 : mary
A - 9-10 : david
A - 10-11 : john
B - 8-9 : john
B - 9-10 : clair
B - 10-11 : david
C - 8-9 : david
C - 9-10 : john
C - 10-11 : clair

Allocation #7:
A - 8-9 : mary
A - 9-10 : john
A - 10-11 : david
B - 8-9 : david
B - 9-10 : clair
B - 10-11 : john
C - 8-9 : john
C - 9-10 : david
C - 10-11 : clair

Allocation #8:
A - 8-9 : mary
A - 9-10 : john
A - 10-11 : david
B - 8-9 : john
B - 9-10 : david
B - 10-11 : clair
C - 8-9 : david
C - 9-10 : clair
C - 10-11 : john

Allocation #9:
A - 8-9 : david
A - 9-10 : john
A - 10-11 : mary
B - 8-9 : john
B - 9-10 : clair
B - 10-11 : david
C - 8-9 : clair
C - 9-10 : david
C - 10-11 : john

Allocation #10:
A - 8-9 : david
A - 9-10 : john
A - 10-11 : mary
B - 8-9 : clair
B - 9-10 : david
B - 10-11 : john
C - 8-9 : john
C - 9-10 : clair
C - 10-11 : david

Allocation #11:
A - 8-9 : david
A - 9-10 : mary
A - 10-11 : john
B - 8-9 : john
B - 9-10 : david
B - 10-11 : clair
C - 8-9 : clair
C - 9-10 : john
C - 10-11 : david

Allocation #12:
A - 8-9 : david
A - 9-10 : mary
A - 10-11 : john
B - 8-9 : clair
B - 9-10 : john
B - 10-11 : david
C - 8-9 : john
C - 9-10 : david
C - 10-11 : clair
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a bipartite graph as follows:

1. Create a vertex on one slide for each resource time slot, like "resource A, 9-10"
2. Create a vertex on the other side for each resource requirement, like "John needs resource A"
3. Connect each time slot to all of the requirements for its resource.

Now your problem becomes a [maximum weight bipartite matching](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/), which you can solve most easily using Kuhn's/Hungarian/Ford-Fulkerson/Edmonds-Karp algorithm (those are all essentially the same thing for this problem).